# In the DC Universe does Batman know that Clark Kent is Superman?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

In the DC universe, i.e the main DC continuity,has it ever been mentioned whether Batman knows that Clark Kent is actually Superman?

Comment: Which DC Universe? They've had a lot of them. In most which contain a Batman and Superman, they are aware of each others identities.

Comment: I would expect so... http://i1.wp.com/nerdbastards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Batman-V-Superman-blanket-fight.jpg

Comment: Richard's answer covers that; The Trinity War was, and more or less remains, in the current main continuity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep. Depending on the continuity, they've known for a very long time. Let's not forget that Batman is the world's greatest detective and Superman has x-ray vision.

**[Superman #76](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_76)**
[image]

[**JLA: Trinity War**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_War)
[image]

[**Adventures of Superman #440**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Adventures_of_Superman_Vol_1_440)
[image]

**[Justice League: War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War)**

**[Justice League: Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series))**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, many times in different, always entertaining ways, they discover each other's identities.

My favorite is in All-Star Superman where superman gives clues to Batman to see if he can determine the identity and they each call out the other's secret... it's very similar to Adventures of Superman #440 that Richard posts above.

If you want, however, one of the arguably best Justice League stories of all time that deals heavily with secrets identities and all of the members knowing each other's identities, then you must read Frank Miller's Identity Crisis.